# HTML5 Semantics- Including page title inside a section

Tags: css, html

I am trying to organize a page layout that has a large "hero" section at the top of the page which would include the page title.

From what I've seen, the hero should be separated into its own `<section>`. But according to the W3 validator, a `<section>` should not include an `<h1>` tag since it's a top level heading.

How should I go about displaying the page title inside of a hero?

```
<body>

  <header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="hero">
      <h1>Page title</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
      <p>The page's content</p>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: you may use **h2** instead. h1 is generally use as a title for the whole page. But these are good practise, you may use h1 inside section

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for your comment, but I AM using the h1 as the title for the whole page... should I just use an h2 and not use an h1 anywhere?

Comment: you may change section by a simple div -- or apply the class hero directly to h1

Comment: Where did you learn that hero should be separated into it's own section? A `section` that contains only `h1` is nonsense if we are talking semantics. Your `h1` is related to the content that follows, right? Then the content and the `h1` should be within the same section. If you want to style the `h1` as a hero, then as @TemaniAfif suggested, you can put it in a `div` element.

Comment: Search bots consider `h1` elements as an important ranking indicator to what the page content pertains and how it may relate to other ranking indicators like the page `title` tag, `meta` tags, and other schema - so if ranking is going to be important, never exclude the `h1`. Have you tried wrapping the `h1` element in a `header` element tag instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search bots consider `h1` elements as an important ranking indicator to what the page content pertains and how it may relate to other ranking indicators like the page `title` tag, `meta` tags, and other schema - so if ranking is going to be important, never exclude the `h1`

Consider using the `<header>` tag instead:

```
<header>
  <h1>Main Page Title</h1>
  <img src="mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="MDN logo">
</header>
```

> The  element is not sectioning content and therefore does not introduce a new section in the outline. That said, a header element is intended to usually contain the surrounding section's heading (an h1–h6 element), but this is not required.

Src: `<header>`  [HTML | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)